# Random array elements

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm very new to coding.

I'm writing this code and I'm struggling because I need to make a code that makes an array with 8 random integers and then it swaps the largest integer with the first number in the array.

When doing this though I'm getting an error and I cannot seem to fix it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class finalExam {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random spinner = new Random();

        int [] userInputs = new int [8];

        for (int i = 0; i < userInputs.length; i++) {
            userInputs[i] = spinner.nextInt(100)+1;
            System.out.println(userInputs[i]);
        }

        int largest = userInputs[0];
        
        for(int j = 1; j < userInputs.length; j++) {
            if(userInputs[j] > largest)
                largest = userInputs[j];
        }

        System.out.println("Your largest number is: " + largest);

        int holder;
        int [] arr = new int[101];

        for (int m = 0; m <= arr.length; m++) {
            holder = largest;
            userInputs[0] = userInputs[largest];
            holder = userInputs[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. "An error" isn't particularly descriptive.

Comment: *maybe* the error message (and stack trace) helps by giving more details like what the error is and where it happens - almost essential to solve it - please at very least include the error message  in the question! (Do the code really need that many empty lines - scrolling does not make a code easier to read)

Comment: `userInputs[largest]` seems suspicious since `largest` will be a value from 1-100, and `userInputs` has a length of 8.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the last bit of your code. `userInputs[largest]` is out of bound because the array is only 8 integers long (while largest can have a value of 100).

Since you need the position of the largest number, you'll have to save it in `largestPosition` when you identify which number is the largest, like so:

```
int largest = userInputs[0];
int largestPosition = 0;
        
for(int j = 1; j < userInputs.length; j++) {
    if(userInputs[j] > largest){
         largest = userInputs[j];
         largestPosition = j;
    }
}
```

That said, the loop which you used at the end also isn't needed here. You could just swap the first value of the array with the largest one using this method:

```
int first = userInputs[0];
userInputs[0] = largest;
userInputs[largestPosition] = first;
```

Comment: Hi Slaymut, I've slightly changed your answer. Note that the "regards" etc. is always left out; the answer should be as concise as possible. I've used single back ticks to use inline code as you can see in the [edit]. If you ever need `<br>` then you can just use double space right before the end of line / enter, is't the same thing as br in Markdown.

Comment: Thank you guys sorry I just realised I didn't even include the error code I got, but thank you guys for helping it worked